# FreeBSD 8.3 - kernel size does not change after build

Tags: kernel, freebsd

I've copied a GENERIC configuration file located in /usr/src/sys/i386/conf, changed its name to MYKERNEL, modified it, paarticulary deleted RAID, fire wire and floppy disc support. Then ran
cd /usr/src
make buildkernel KERNCONF=MYKERNEL

the build succeeded, but when I checked in /boot/kernel the size of the kernel remained the same as in kernel.old. what did I do wrong? How can I reduce the kernel size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `make buildkernel` only builds the kernel and modules. It doesn't install them.

To do that you also need to run `make installkernel`.

Comment: Thank you! I already found it, but in case somebody has similar question this is the right way to solve the problem